# How to use cloud function trigger based on two collections documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a collection ReferalCodes in which each document is specified has these values where 'mine' value is false 'msg' value is false and mycode is user referal codes.

```
  appliedcode: ""
  mine:false
  msg:false
  mycode:"ASDF4G"
  referals : []
```

And User has one more collection UserTransaction which have a field 'CountTrans' which is initialized as 0 when this value is 1 i want to trigger a function to check value of mine and appliedcode if the value of mine is true then and applied code have value of length 6 then i want to update the UserTransaction of that user and the appliedcode is referal code of some another user want to change UserTransaction of that user also

```
      const functions = require('firebase-functions');
  const admin = require('firebase-admin');


  const { user } = require('firebase-functions/lib/providers/auth');
 admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.getCount= functions.firestore
.document('UserTransactions/{id}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => { 
const newTransdata = change.after.data();
const previousTransData = change.before.data();
const docid = context.params.docid;


if(newTransdata.CountTrans === 1) {
    const referalData = await 
admin.firestore.collection('ReferalCodes').doc(docid).get()
    const mine = referalData.mine;
    const appliedCode = referalData.appliedCode;
    let codes = [];
    var myfrindid;
    if(mine === true && appliedCode !== null) {
        const friendData = await 
admin.firestore.collection('ReferalCodes').doc('codes').get();
        var referalcodes = friendData['ReferalCodes'];
        referalcodes.forEach((items) =>{
            if (items['code'] == appliedCode) {
              myfrindid = items['id'];
            }
          });
        await 
admin.firestore.collection('ReferalCodes').doc(docid).update({
            msg: true
        })
    
    }else{

    }
}
});
```

Comment: Instead of describing your code, can you edit your question to show the [actual minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i have done only first statement to get the values of UserTransaction after that i am stucked and i am not able to proceed

Comment: Thanks for that code. I'm still having a hard time understanding what the problem is though. When you run this code, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: i want to check the value of newTransdata.CountTrans === 1 if it is possible i want to extract the data from other collection 'ReferalCodes' and get the value and check some other condition

Comment: I have done some other codes but i am getting error error  Parsing error: Unexpected token admin. I have again uploaded the other code please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Consulting the official [documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) is explained how to handle events on your database and trigger some different kind of triggers depending on your needs, for example:

onWrite(), which triggers when data is created, updated, or deleted in Realtime Database.

- onCreate(), which triggers when new data is created in Realtime Database
- onUpdate(), which triggers when data is updated in Realtime Database
- onDelete(), which triggers when data is deleted from Realtime Database

For example, the first argument passed your onUpdate handler function is a Change object, this object has two properties, before and after, both [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.datasnapshot) objects. These DataSnapshot objects describe the contents of the database before and after the change that triggered the function.

```
exports.foo = functions.database.ref('/location-of-interest')
.onUpdate((change) => {
    const before = change.before  // DataSnapshot before the change
    const after = change.after  // DataSnapshot after the change
})
```